# iOS swift collection view

Tags: ios, swift

i have created collection view in swift
 language i need to add  images to those cells how can   i add images?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to create collection view in interface builder, subclass uicollectionviewcell add outlet for uiimageview

```
class colCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Add one dynamic cell in that collectionview, change class of that cell to your subclass. Drop UIImageView on that cell, connect your outlet and access it from UICollectionView delegate/datasource functions.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as colCollectionViewCell
     cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named:"myimagename")
    return cell
}
```

Here is a great tutorial for UICollectionView: http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

Answer (score 0):

you can use Haneke

Sample

```
if let urlString = self.data?["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"]{
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString.stringValue)
            self.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
        }
```

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2015/02/24/uicollectionview-tutorial-in-swift-using-alamofire-haneke-and-swiftyjson/